# learning sources about Ihara Coefficient

Tags: reference-request, mathematics-education, graph-theory

Do we have any good sources(lecture notes or books) for learning about $Ihara$ Coefficient?

Is there any relation between $Ihara$ Coefficient and the eigenvalues of graphs?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Igor Rivin's suggestion I found the thesis of Matthew Horton (student of Stark and Terras) pretty interesting : ['Ihara zeta functions of irregular graphs'](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/3ws358jm).

Comment: That's a nice reference!

Comment: Thanks Igor!<br>
Another nice reference I just found again is Audrey Terras' recent book "A stroll through the garden of graph zeta function" with an earlier draft available from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Terras)

Comment: Dear Raymond,
Thank you very much for your most helpful answers.

Wishes

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the good sources are the articles by H. Stark and A. Terras on zeta functions of graphs.

Comment: Thanks Dear Rivin. Your answer was very helpful.

Sincerely
 

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend this paper: [The coefficients of the Ihara zeta function](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5075/581da46a7ce2e457e329afc76ba78412dddc.pdf)
by Geoffrey Scott and Christopher Storm